# Sending post request to backend returns empty req.body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to connect react to express server,but when I try to recieve the data that I sent with the react app, in the req.body of the backend I get an empty object, this is my react code:

```
export default function App() {
  let [text, setText] = useState("");
  const sendToServer = () => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:4000/test", {
        text: text
      })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={sendToServer}>Send</button>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is my backend:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors('http://localhost:3000'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);

});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`server listening`);
});

app.listen(4000);
```

I used proxy in the package.json file, but it still doesn't work.
on the /test request I get an empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));`

Comment: @Chrissisbeast kindly requesting you to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Kindly requesting you double check this works, the one below suggesting the change use->post is necessary too.

Answer (score 1):

Change `app.use` to `app.post`

```
app.post("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Docs for references [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should add res.data instead of res